# Filter for internal Links js / javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have checked, but do not find this answered yet.
What Iam trying to do is make internal links external via using a js-filter.

e.g.: Someone enters the link www.stackoverflow.com or just stackoverflow.com to his profil on my page.
What will happen when clicked is that the link will interpreted as a internal link such as https://mypage/stackoverflow.com
What I want the filter to do is that if it see someone entered as said, test if it is supposed to be a https or http link and respond with this.

What I tried so far (not working):

```
    .filter('externallink', function () {
    var PATTERN_FOR_EXTERNAL_URLS = /^(\w+:)?\/\//;
    var href = $(a).attr('href');
    return href !== undefined && href.search(PATTERN_FOR_EXTERNAL_URLS) !== -1;
};

$.expr[':'].internal = function (a) {
    return $(a).attr('href') !== undefined && !$.expr[':'].external(a);
};)
```

All solutions I found so far where in php or java, which does not help me. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you!
Flo

Comment: Isn't it enough to prepend `http://` if no protocol exists for a given link?

Comment: Yes I thought so, but wouldnt that mean, that if someone added the link like: "https://www.stackoverflow.com" it would direct to "http://https://www.stackoverflow.com" ?

Comment: I checked it. It does not work that way.... So I still need a filter function.